# @RequestParam not accepting '&' in a string sent from request, stores all characters before & and truncates the rest

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

**Value sent from ajax:** Droit & stratégie des affaires au Maroc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getValue")
@ResponseBody
public void getTOCFromML(@RequestParam("doc_id") String doc_id, HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request)
{
System.out.println(doc_id);
}

output: Droit
Expected output: Droit & stratégie des affaires au Maroc
```

`@RequestParam("doc_id")` stores the value before `&` character and ignores the rest of the characters (for some security purpose i believe) .

But i need the full string for further execution.

Please let me know how to make this work

**Update1:**
Only '&' character causing the problem for me.

when below value given as input, it works fine

```
Value : La Semaine Juridique Notariale et Immobilière
```

**Update2:**
 i used encodeURIComponent(string) in javascript ajax req. its working now.
thankyou

Comment: please add what you sent the the `service` as a `String`

Comment: Are you sure you have url encoded the param before sending it to the server? Otherwise the & symbols splits the value from the next parameter in the url !

Comment: @VikrantKashyap could you refer first line in my question?. that is the value. did you ask for the value?

Comment: I think you should put a `\`  (forward slash)  just before  `&` Operator. this might solve your problem @divine

Comment: @ReneM.its not an encoding issue. i have updated it in my question. could you refer it and let me know a possible solution for the issue?

Comment: _"This is not an encoding issue. Only '&' character causing the problem for me. "_ How is that not an encoding issue? The URL must not contain a literal `&`, it needs to be encoded.

Comment: @divine This is, in fact, an encoding issue. Please see RFC 3986, paragraph 2.2. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2

Comment: @zeroflagL sorry...i meant french encoding issue..url encoding yes, that issue exists. i misunderstood

Comment: guys, its working for me now. i used encodeURIComponent(string) in javascript ajax req. one buddy posted this in answer comments. someone deleted the answer entirely. i have used this function for another scenario but didnt think of using it here. thank you guys

Comment: @PeterKirby i'm going through the reference. thank you

Comment: @ReneM.lol.. i didnt think it first.. ty

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
   URLEncoder.encode()
```

Hope it will help.